# supply a warning of R version in R package

Tags: r

I am building an R package and it requires R version >= 2.15.2. I listed this information in my DESCRIPTION file `Depends = "R (>= 2.15.2)"`. However, I am not sure if someone got a previous version of R (say 2.14) and tried to install my package, will the package be installed or completely halted? If it can still be installed, how can I issue a warning message to tell the end-users to use the appropriate R version? Thanks!

Comment: I think R will simply refuse to install the package ("completely halted" in your terminology), with an error message; I don't remember the exact error message but I think it will be sufficiently informative that a reasonably astute user will realize they need a more up-to-date version.  I don't think you have any option to insert a custom message at this point ...

Comment: @BenBolker thanks a lot! just a confirmation from experts ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)

> Version dependencies in the ‘Depends’ and ‘Imports’ fields are used
>   by library when it loads the package,  a install.packages checks
>   versions for the ‘Depends’, ‘Imports’ and (for dependencies = TRUE)
>   ‘Suggests’ fields.

So The R INSTALL facilities check if the version of R used is recent enough for the package being installed, if not it will not be installed.

**EDIT**
thanks to @benbolker comment; if the R version is old ,the 
error message is `ERROR: this R is version %s, package '%s' requires R %s %s`, which should be sufficiently informative .

Comment: snooping around in the source code (since I don't want to bother installing an old version of R to test it); the error message is `"ERROR: this R is version %s, package '%s' requires R %s %s"`, which should be sufficiently informative ...